# IMPORTRANGE with Blacklist on Google SHeets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm quite novice so I apologize if this is obvious. I'm trying to have an import range show names and another value from another google sheet, but exclude those from a blacklist. I have pasted the formula I'm currently working with below. Any ideas?

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXX", "XXXX!$A:$B"), " skipping != 'Blacklist'!$A:$A")
```

The import range it pulls from is a Filter already, I've pasted that below. Could it be worked there?

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('XXXXX'!$A:$B, 'XXXXXX'!$H:$H = "ABCD")," ")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FILTER is my preferred way of removing from a list.

[image: Image of blacklist filter]

Here is the formula

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,NOT(COUNTIF(B2:B3,A2:A6)))
```

You can think of it like

```
=FILTER( list ,NOT(COUNTIF( needle , haystack)))
```

Usually you use this to whitelist a document (hence why I dedicated this formula to memory in a needle-haystack fashion.) But by throwing in the `NOT` in the criteria of the filter, it works great for blacklisting too!

As to why it works, I'm not sure, my best guess is when google sheets is running through the `COUNTIF` for any given cell if it meets the criteria it will return a '1' which is truthy and it includes it in the results. This also allows us to compare un-even amounts of data. ie. `B2:B3` rather than `B2:B6`